# Best OpenLDAP authentication option?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, openldap

I want to prevent users from browsing other users names, security (of course) and performance

Comment: You can do that from within the OpenLDAP configuration. See the documentation.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do with OpenLDAP?

Do you currently have an openLDAP server running and want to use it for authentications for your web application?

OpenLDAP by definition is a directory server. It's designed to let users browse the information of other users in the directory.

If you want to protect access to the LDAP server, I would use network level access restrictions to only let your IIS machine access it.

Sorry if I did not understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

Use Maching/Network permissions to restrict access to your openLDAP server to *ONLY* your management machine, and your IIS machine. Thus only those two machines can browse your directories.

Use SSL for all communication with your openLDAP server. That will require connecting to port 636.

By default, openLDAP stores passwords in the clear; instead force it to use salted hash. OpenLDAP comes with a command line utility that will hash passwords for you.